# how to resolve org.pdfclown.util.NotImplementedException

Tags: java, pdfclown

I am getting below exception when i load one of the chinese document not all chinese documents.My requirement document is not encoded format and  it looks like normal/plain chinese document.As per confidential concerns i am not providing my requirement  document.Kindly provide your inputs for support all the chinese pdf document.

```
org.pdfclown.util.NotImplementedException: Encrypted files are currently not supported.
    at org.pdfclown.files.File.<init>(File.java:147)
    at org.pdfclown.files.File.<init>(File.java:115)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message

> Encrypted files are currently not supported

means what it says: You have tried to open an encrypted PDF file but PDF Clown does not support encryption.

You may not be aware that the PDF in question is encrypted because the PDF format has a concept of encryption using a default password. When a PDF viewer opens an encrypted PDF, it first checks whether this default password can be used for decryption; if it can, the viewer does not ask the user for a password but opens the PDF with that default password.

This concept is necessary for PDFs with old-style permission limitations or owner/user roles because they could only be applied to encrypted PDFs.

Concerning your request for *inputs for support all the chinese pdf document*... This is not possible using PDF Clown in its current state and considering its development stasis it likely will never be.